# Apache2 - Dynamically map url on files ystem

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm tying at the moment to dynamically map a url to the file system.

e.g.:
www.example.com/~svn/myrepo   < to >   /var/svn-repos/myrepo

My approach:

```
<Location /~svn/([a-ZA-Z0-9-_]+)>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/svn-repos/$1
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn_all.passwd
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Any idea how that works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Location /~svn/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos/
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn_all.passwd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```